# Java class naming rules

Tags: java, naming-conventions

In JAVA, class name must always be the same as file name, but sometimes file contains multiple classes. Only single class(or interface) in file can be public, and it must have the same name as file. But how is the file name determined if it has multiple classes (or interfaces) that are not public?

```
interface Foo {}

class Bar{}
```

**Some people seem to be confused about this question**

I actually know that it'll work regardless if I choose Foo or Bar as a file name. However what interest's me is if there are some kind of convention of naming the class.

Why don't I name it whatever I feel like it? Because i'm actually writing an application that refactors code, and whenever it renames classes, i need to know how and when to change my filename.

**So far i think the right way is:**

if class has a public node, use it's name as filename, 
else just pick the first node, so in this example **Foo** would win. So I simplify the question: is this the right way, or is there something more to it?

Comment: You should try it, compile it, and look at how the .class files are created

Comment: It'll work both ways, the question is regarding conventions.

Comment: you can choose it as you want

Comment: The **convention** is to make one public and make sure that the file name matches.

Comment: Could you kind people read my edited question?

Comment: A reasonable convention would be to use 2 different files, since it can be hard to find your classes otherwise. IMHO a second class should only be put in the same .java file, if it's only used in that file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quoting the Java Language Specification, section 7.6 [Top Level Type Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6) :

> If and only if packages are stored in a file system (§7.2), the host system **may choose** to enforce the restriction that it is a compile-time error if a type is not found in a file under a name composed of the type name plus an extension (such as `.java` or `.jav`) if either of the following is true:
>
> - The type is referred to by code in other compilation units of the package in which the type is declared.
> - The type is declared `public` (and therefore is potentially accessible from code in other packages).
>
> *This restriction implies that there must be at most one such type per compilation unit. This restriction makes it easy for a Java compiler to find a named class within a package. In practice, many programmers choose to put each class or interface type in its own compilation unit, whether or not it is public or is referred to by code in other compilation units.*

So, as you can see, it is not a requirement that "class name must always be the same as file name", as you said it.

It is simply a way to allow *some* compilers an easy way to find the class source code during compilation.

But, more importantly, it also help **humans** find the source code. If you see a reference to class `com.example.Foo`, you know exactly where to find it, because it's going to be in file `com/example/Foo.java`.

Non-public (package private) top-level classes, can technically be placed in files of any name, and multiple such classes can be bundled in a single file, but that makes them difficult to find. For this reason, I've seen a guideline (don't remember where) that said that you should always put top-level classes in their own file, with one exception:

- If the non-public class is *only* used by one other class, it's ok to place it in the same compilation unit (.java file) as that other class.

Basically this means that you should consider any top-level class, whose name is not the file name, to be "file-scoped", even though it's technically packages-scoped.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 rules to follow:

**1st Rule:** The class can have either package (default) or public visibility

**2nd Rule:** Teh class which you have defined as public must be implemented in a .java source file with the same name, however classes that are non-public can be with other name in source files.

Comment: @Benedictus:- You should always follow the best practice and the best practice is to put every class in the its own source file regardless of its visibility, except for non-public classes. It makes it very convenient for other people who want to check a class declaration by simply browsing folders and looking for specific file names.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with how **I** should write my classes, but rather how to parse them.

Comment: @Benedictus:- You are looking for convention and that is what is being followed.

Comment: @Benedictus:- You may find this interesting: http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=7555